# Without toast JSON response is not working why?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I tried MYSQL, PHP JSON and VOlley request to log in to the user but when I do without toasting the final response user is not get logged in but when I use toast user gets logged in? why is it so

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        /////////////////////THIS TOAST I AM TALKING ABOUT

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        }
                        if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                            if(jsonObject.getString("message").equals("ERROR")){
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Verify.class);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I think toast creates a delay time then you have enough time for initializing. I suggest use a boolean method for the next part of your code , and with "if" statement check for proper returning.Or use ordinal calling method manner  class.method1().method2() . In this manner method2 does not execute until the method1 returns the result.

Comment: I also got same problem, can you elaborate once in this scenario